# Sequalize relationship betwen same model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am creating a chat application and trying to create a relationship between User and User through friendship. So far I can create a relationship, but in the end only one user assigned a friend. I'm using Express, sequalize with postgress deployed to heroku. I don't know how to achieve it, any help is appreciated

migration:
`` `enter code here`await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, } }, }); await queryInterface.createTable('friendships', { id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, }, user: { type: DataTypes.UUID, allowNull: false, references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' }, }, friend: { type: DataTypes.UUID, allowNull: false, references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' }, }, status: { type: DataTypes.ENUM('PENDING', 'ACCEPTED', 'DENIED'), allowNull: false, defaultValue: 'PENDING',     }, }); ``

friendship model:

```
    Friendship.init(
    {
    id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    user: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
    model: 'users',
    key: 'id',
    },
    },
    friend: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
    model: 'users',
    key: 'id',
    },
    },
    status: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM('PENDING', 'ACCEPTED', 'DENIED'),
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 'PENDING',
    },
    },
    {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false,
    modelName: 'friendship',
    }
    );
```

associations:

```
    User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'friends', through: Friendship, foreignKey: 'user', 
    otherKey: 'friend' });
    Friendship.belongsTo(User, { as: 'info', foreignKey: 'friend' });
```

controller:

```
    export const addFriend = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
    const { friendId } = req.body;
    const userId = req.decodedToken?.id;

    const friend = await User.findByPk(friendId, {
    attributes: { exclude: ['passwordHash'] },
    include: [{ model: User, as: 'friends' }],
    });

    if (friend)
    await Friendship.create({
    user: userId,
    friend: friend.id,
    status: 'PENDING',
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
    } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'The server cannot create the user' });
    console.log(e);
    }
    };
```

response:

```
    "users": {
    "count": 2,
    "rows": [
    {
    "id": "e7c7ce39-953a-45e7-a892-a5f99554382e",
    "email": "admin",
    "username": "admin",
    "name": null,
    "surname": null,
    "age": null,
    "public": true,
    "image": null,
    "friends": [
    {
    "id": "13029ad9-7199-47d5-bd1c-7d939b26150e",
    "email": "admin2",
    "username": "admin",
    "passwordHash": "$2b$10$GajlewYeiGvUOOV08YOzLuedV/8.KJNUeHB4WPKlUFxErj91ljfWq",
    "name": null,
    "surname": null,
    "age": null,
    "public": true,
    "image": null,
    "friendship": {
    "id": "a78b9336-f5a6-4153-b3e1-e44dbe1cc7a6",
    "user": "e7c7ce39-953a-45e7-a892-a5f99554382e",
    "friend": "13029ad9-7199-47d5-bd1c-7d939b26150e",
    "status": "PENDING"
    }
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "id": "13029ad9-7199-47d5-bd1c-7d939b26150e",
    "email": "admin2",
    "username": "admin",
    "name": null,
    "surname": null,
    "age": null,
    "public": true,
    "image": null,
    "friends": []
    }
```

Edit:
I made something like this, it's not perfect, but it's good for me

```
  User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'friends', through: Friendship, foreignKey: 'user' });
  User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'friend', through: Friendship, foreignKey: 'friend' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider a many to many relationship.

An user can be a friend of many users.
Many users can be friends of one user.

You may found the how-to implement in the official doc: [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#many-to-many-relationships).
Basically, use belongsToMany in both associations:

> Implementation
> The main way to do this in Sequelize is as follows:
>
> ```
> const Movie = sequelize.define('Movie', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
> const Actor = sequelize.define('Actor', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
> Movie.belongsToMany(Actor, { through: 'ActorMovies' });
> Actor.belongsToMany(Movie, { through: 'ActorMovies' });
> ```